# ElasticSearch Histogram and Kibana with start and end time

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch, kibana

All of my ElasticSearch documents have a StartTime and an EndTime. I would like to build a histogram that has the count of documents for a given time bucket e.g. 30 minutes such that all documents have StartTime < BucketEndTime and EndTime > BucketStartTime. How would I construct such a search query? How can I show the results in Kibana?

Comment: Can you explain better what do you want to show in the histogram? It is possible to do a query like the one that you are describing but I do not know what you want to show in the graph

Comment: My documents contain information about jobs. What I ultimately would like to show is the number of concurrent jobs for a given time period.

Comment: I am also interested in an answer to this question. It seems like a rather common use case. The answer below is not completely true since you can use any query for aggregation and this is one (very cumbersome way) to solve the problem. Also, the question includes an element of how best to do it in Elasticsearch. Is that as shown in the query above?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible for Kibana 4.0.2 (current latest version). The reason being here you want to aggregate based on calculation over multiple fields (StartTime & EndTime) and that is not supported by Kibana right now.